# How to open memory data with ogr in rasterstats function?

Tags: python, vector, ogr, zonal-statistics, rasterstats

I would like to reuse vector data created in memory in another function called `rasterstats` ([source code](https://gist.github.com/perrygeo/5667173), [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/rasterstats/#description)):

I have a function that creates vector data:

```
def createPolygons:    
    memoryDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('MEMORY')
    memoryDatasource = memoryDriver.CreateDataSource('memoryData')
    memoryLayer = memoryDatasource.CreateLayer('memoryLayer', geom_type = ogr.wkbPolygon)
    [...]
    return memoryDatasource
```

I would then like to use the output (polygons) of that function in:

```
zonal_stats(vector, raster, band=1)
```

Which results in errors like this:

```
ValueError("Can't parse %s as a geojson Feature object" % obj)
```

[`ogr.Open()`](http://www.gdal.org/ogr__api_8h.html#a2da3630231780d519543d1679c83e62f) in `rasterstats` seems unable to open my vector data. I have tried returning the `memoryLayer` and the `memoryDatasource` in `createPolygons` and using those as well as their names as input in `zonal_stats`. The memory data certainly exists, because I can access it after debugging the result of `createPolygons` with functions such as GetFeatureCount().

The problem is that the data does not have a path, and this seems to be required as input for `ogr.Open()`. [However, memory is listed as a possible driver for `ogr.Open()`](http://www.gdal.org/drv_memory.html). This side says also: *There is no way to open an existing Memory datastore.*

I am unsure, whether it is possible to reuse the memory data in another function and if yes, how to realize this.